# bash function - Get function stdout value inside a variable and modify variables outside the function

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Due to a specific need, I need all the stdout outputs of a bash function be stored in a variable ("F_MY_FUNC_R"), but I also need that function to modify the value of certain variables ("VAL_A" and "VAL_B") according to code below.

**QUESTION:** Why are the variables VAL_A and VAL_B not being modified? Is there a way around this?

CODE

```
VAL_A="none"
VAL_B="none"
f_my_func() {
    echo "some info some info some info some info some info "
    echo "some info some info some info some info some info "
    echo "some info some info some info some info some info "
    echo "some info some info some info some info some info "
    VAL_A="some value"
    VAL_B="some value"
}
F_MY_FUNC_R=$(f_my_func)
echo "$F_MY_FUNC_R"
echo "$VAL_A"
echo "$VAL_B"
```

OUTPUT

```
[root@localhost some_folder]# echo "$F_MY_FUNC_R"
some info some info some info some info some info 
some info some info some info some info some info 
some info some info some info some info some info 
some info some info some info some info some info 
[root@localhost some_folder]# echo "$VAL_A"
none
[root@localhost some_folder]# echo "$VAL_B"
none
```

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: As far as I recall, command substitution `$( ... )` is [performed in a sub-shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and therefore cannot modify the variables of the shell from which it is called. Can you for test reasons check what happens if you simply call `f_my_func` without placing it in the `$( ... )` construct?

Comment: It is a specific need... The original function is huge so I would like to keep the outputs of this function (`echo` basically) in a log file that is generated with the entry in `F_MY_FUNC_R`. Thanks! =D

Comment: If you want the output in a log file why don't you just redirect the output to a log file?

Comment: Because the logging scheme is made up of many legacy components. Apparently, if I can redirect stdout to a variable, I will be able to solve the problem. This works: `f_my_func > f_my_func_op; F_MY_FUNC_R=$(cat f_my_func_op); rm -f "f_my_func_op"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my "dirty" solution... =D

**NOTE:** As I say my real function is huge so I would like to keep the outputs of this function (`echo` basically) in a log file that is generated with the entry in `F_MY_FUNC_OP`. Other than that, my logging scheme uses `F_MY_FUNC_OP` and is made up of many legacy components.

```
VAL_A="none"
VAL_B="none"
f_my_func() {
    echo "$(date)"
    VAL_A="some value"
    VAL_B="some value"
}
f_my_func > f_my_func_op 2>&1
F_MY_FUNC_OP=$(cat f_my_func_op)
rm -f "f_my_func_op"
echo "$F_MY_FUNC_OP"
echo "$VAL_A"
echo "$VAL_B"
```

This way I can execute the function and redirecting its stderr and stdout to a file at the same time that I allow the manipulation of variables external to the function (case of "$VAL_A" and "$VAL_B"), otherwise ("F_MY_FUNC_OP=$(f_my_func)" or "F_MY_FUNC_OP=`f_my_func`", for example) the function will being executed in a "subshell" and the manipulation of these variables will not be possible.

Thanks to @jesse_b, @AdminBee and @Isaac! **=D**

Answer (score 2):

It is a fundamental rule in shell that a sub-shell **can not** modify its parent variables nor environment. Executing the function inside a sub-shell `$(f_my_func)` is affected by that rule and the parent variables VAL_A and VAL_B are not changed.

If you do need to change parent variables in a function, then don't capture the output of the function, make the output some other variable:

```
VAL_A="none"
VAL_B="none"
f_my_func() {
    nl=$'\n'
    F_MY_FUNC_R="some info some info some info some info some info $nl"
    F_MY_FUNC_R+="some info some info some info some info some info $nl"
    F_MY_FUNC_R+="some info some info some info some info some info $nl"
    F_MY_FUNC_R+="some info some info some info some info some info "
    VAL_A="some value"
    VAL_B="some value"
}
f_my_func
echo "$F_MY_FUNC_R"
echo "$VAL_A"
echo "$VAL_B"
```